# Remote disable not working for Android app in Worklight 6.1.0.01

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I have disabled the app for iOS and Android and we are able to see the messages with access disabled on iOS. But for android its not appering, Can anyone please suggest what would have gone wrong.

Worklight version: Server version: 6.1.0.01.20140922-2007

Sample app LogCat:

```
10-29 08:21:55.476: I/CordovaLog(3123): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
10-29 08:21:55.476: D/CordovaActivity(3123): CordovaActivity.onCreate()
10-29 08:21:55.484: D/dalvikvm(3123): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 318K, 10% free 3644K/4024K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
10-29 08:21:55.484: I/dalvikvm-heap(3123): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.916MB for 2412012-byte allocation
10-29 08:21:55.492: D/dalvikvm(3123): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 5999K/6380K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
10-29 08:21:55.516: V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider(3123): Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {52842af8}
10-29 08:21:55.516: I/LibraryLoader(3123): Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
10-29 08:21:55.516: I/chromium(3123): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(116)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
10-29 08:21:55.516: I/BrowserStartupController(3123): Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
10-29 08:21:55.532: E/AudioManagerAndroid(3123): BLUETOOTH permission is missing!
10-29 08:21:55.532: D/libEGL(3123): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
10-29 08:21:55.540: D/(3123): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb902af48, tid 3123
10-29 08:21:55.552: D/libEGL(3123): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
10-29 08:21:55.552: D/libEGL(3123): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
10-29 08:21:55.600: W/chromium(3123): [WARNING:mailbox_synchronizer.cc(36)] MailboxSync not supported due to missing EGL image/fence support
10-29 08:21:55.604: D/dalvikvm(3123): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 46K, 6% free 6273K/6604K, paused 1ms, total 1ms
10-29 08:21:55.604: I/dalvikvm-heap(3123): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.603MB for 2536932-byte allocation
10-29 08:21:55.616: D/dalvikvm(3123): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 8750K/9084K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
10-29 08:21:55.628: W/chromium(3123): [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(890)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
10-29 08:21:55.708: D/CordovaWebView(3123): CordovaWebView is running on device made by: Genymotion
10-29 08:21:55.712: D/JsMessageQueue(3123): Set native->JS mode to 2
10-29 08:21:55.712: D/CordovaActivity(3123): CordovaActivity.init()
10-29 08:21:55.712: W/com.worklight.androidgap.analytics.WLAnalytics(3123): TLF_configurator.enable was called, but the required Tealeaf libraries are not present in the classpath.
10-29 08:21:55.712: D/Whitelist(3123): Unlimited access to network resources
10-29 08:21:55.712: I/CordovaLog(3123): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
10-29 08:21:55.712: D/CordovaActivity(3123): Resuming the App
10-29 08:21:55.712: D/CordovaActivity(3123): CB-3064: The errorUrl is null
10-29 08:21:55.716: D/WLDroidGap(3123): New installation/upgrade detected, copying resources and saving new checksum
10-29 08:21:55.744: D/WLDroidGap(3123): no need to check web resource integrity
10-29 08:21:55.868: W/EGL_genymotion(3123): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-29 08:21:55.868: E/OpenGLRenderer(3123): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
10-29 08:21:55.872: E/OpenGLRenderer(3123): MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
10-29 08:21:55.872: E/OpenGLRenderer(3123): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
10-29 08:21:55.872: E/OpenGLRenderer(3123): MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
10-29 08:21:55.872: D/OpenGLRenderer(3123): Enabling debug mode 0
10-29 08:21:55.880: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(3123): Ignore this event
10-29 08:21:56.000: W/EGL_genymotion(3123): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-29 08:21:56.012: D/CordovaWebView(3123): >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/skinLoader.html)
10-29 08:21:56.012: D/PluginManager(3123): init()
10-29 08:21:56.012: D/CordovaWebView(3123): >>> loadUrlNow()
10-29 08:21:56.208: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(3123): Ignore this event
10-29 08:21:56.220: D/CordovaActivity(3123): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/skinLoader.html)
10-29 08:21:56.384: E/AndroidProtocolHandler(3123): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/default/js/skinLoader.js
10-29 08:21:56.580: D/CordovaActivity(3123): onMessage(spinner,stop)
10-29 08:21:56.584: D/CordovaNetworkManager(3123): Connection Type: wifi
10-29 08:21:56.624: I/chromium(3123): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(60)] Async pixel transfers not supported
10-29 08:21:56.628: E/chromium(3123): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder_autogen.h(1082)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:701013B9]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : GetIntegerv: <- error from previous GL command
10-29 08:21:56.636: I/chromium(3123): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(60)] Async pixel transfers not supported
10-29 08:21:56.644: E/chromium(3123): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder_autogen.h(1082)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:B01A17B9]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : GetIntegerv: <- error from previous GL command
10-29 08:21:56.648: E/eglCodecCommon(3123): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
10-29 08:21:56.676: D/CordovaNetworkManager(3123): Connection Type: wifi
10-29 08:21:56.676: D/CordovaActivity(3123): onMessage(networkconnection,wifi)
10-29 08:21:56.732: W/PluginManager(3123): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to Utils.loadSkin blocked the main thread for 17ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
10-29 08:21:56.744: E/eglCodecCommon(3123): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
10-29 08:21:56.744: D/CordovaWebViewClient(3123): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/skinLoader.html)
10-29 08:21:56.744: D/CordovaActivity(3123): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/skinLoader.html)
10-29 08:21:56.744: D/CordovaWebView(3123): >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/default/index.html)
10-29 08:21:56.744: D/PluginManager(3123): init()
10-29 08:21:56.744: D/CordovaWebView(3123): >>> loadUrlNow()
10-29 08:21:56.748: D/CordovaActivity(3123): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/default/index.html)
10-29 08:21:56.960: E/eglCodecCommon(3123): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
10-29 08:21:56.980: D/CordovaActivity(3123): onMessage(spinner,stop)
10-29 08:21:56.980: D/CordovaNetworkManager(3123): Connection Type: wifi
10-29 08:21:56.980: D/CordovaWebViewClient(3123): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/default/index.html)
10-29 08:21:56.980: D/CordovaActivity(3123): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/default/index.html)
10-29 08:21:56.996: D/CordovaNetworkManager(3123): Connection Type: wifi
10-29 08:21:56.996: D/CordovaActivity(3123): onMessage(networkconnection,wifi)
10-29 08:21:57.100: E/eglCodecCommon(3123): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
10-29 08:21:57.400: I/wl.client(3123): WL.Client.init ENTERING
10-29 08:21:57.408: D/NONE(3123): ondeviceready event dispatched
10-29 08:21:57.416: I/wl.client(3123): WL.Client onEnvInit ENTERING
10-29 08:21:57.416: D/NONE(3123): wlclient init started
10-29 08:21:57.420: D/NONE(3123): Read cookies: null
10-29 08:21:57.420: D/NONE(3123): CookieMgr read cookies: {}
10-29 08:21:57.436: W/NONE(3123): Your application is using the WL.OptionsMenu API. Note that, if your application targets Android 3.0 (API level 11) or higher, WL.OptionsMenu might have no effect, depending on the device.
10-29 08:21:57.444: D/NONE(3123): addDeviceIDHeader deviceIDSuccessCallback
10-29 08:21:57.444: D/NONE(3123): connectOnStartup finalizeInit
10-29 08:21:57.448: D/NONE(3123): before: app init onSuccess
10-29 08:21:57.452: D/NONE(3123): after: app init onSuccess
10-29 08:21:57.452: D/NONE(3123): added onPause event handler 
10-29 08:21:57.452: D/NONE(3123): wlclient init success
10-29 08:21:57.828: E/eglCodecCommon(3123): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
10-29 08:21:57.856: E/eglCodecCommon(3123): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
10-29 08:21:57.876: E/eglCodecCommon(3123): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
10-29 08:21:57.900: E/eglCodecCommon(3123): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
10-29 08:21:57.928: E/eglCodecCommon(3123): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
10-29 08:21:57.948: E/eglCodecCommon(3123): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
10-29 08:21:57.972: E/eglCodecCommon(3123): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
10-29 08:21:57.992: E/eglCodecCommon(3123): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
10-29 08:21:58.024: E/eglCodecCommon(3123): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
10-29 08:21:58.044: E/eglCodecCommon(3123): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
10-29 08:21:58.072: E/eglCodecCommon(3123): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
10-29 08:21:58.092: E/eglCodecCommon(3123): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
10-29 08:21:58.132: E/eglCodecCommon(3123): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)



Thanks
djrecker
```

Comment: Would you do us the courtesy and tell us your Worklight version and provide LogCat logs? The basics...

Comment: I will share the logs in some time.

Comment: What you've added is not the logs from LogCat; it is from the Worklight development server.

Comment: I ll check that and post it here. From Android Log cat.

Comment: I suggest that you will first correct the Dojo errors. I suspect they cause things to not work. Right now I do not see this related to Worklight.

Comment: we have created a sample test app and on that as well the android disable feature is not working, Any suggestions on that. Please help. Really appreciate your replies.

Comment: Create a new project and a new empty application that only connects to the server. No Dojo, no adapters, nothing, just connect and then try to disable it. If it works, the problem is in your app and you need to provide it in order to debug.

Comment: HI, I have just tried a sample app, And what i have observed is the access disaled is not working on demo app on android as well.can you please confirm the same. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: I have also compared this behaviour, looks like 6.1.0.1 the access disabled is not working, and 6.1 version both iOS and android are working fine.

Comment: I have tested with Worklight 6.1.0.2 (latest available Fix Pack) and I sucessfully remote-disabled a Hybrid app for the android environment. Install the latest release for Worklight 6.1 from IBM Fix Central.

Comment: Ok great, but the version what we are using is Worklight version :- Server version: 6.1.0.01.20140922-2007, Can you confirm anything on this one, Please let us know.

Comment: No, I can't. 6.1.0.2 is the latest Fix Pack for the 6.1 release, so please upgrade and verify.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In  *android->native-> AndroidManifest.xml*
Add the below line,

```
<activity android:name="com.worklight.wlclient.ui.UIActivity"/>
```

Deploy the app to Worklight Server and Check again.

Comment: This activity shouldn't be removed by the user; I'd be surprised if this would be the culprit. Additionally, you should read the comments, it doesn't sound like that's where this issue is headed.

Answer (score 0):

Per discussion in the comments, Remote Disable appears to be working correctly using the latest 6.1.0.2 Fix Pack release.

My suggestion is to download the latest available iFix for Worklight 6.1 artifacts from IBM Fix Central and try again.